# Make the size in math mode larger with beamer

Tags: relsize

Because of my convenience and some other things from adaptation of things to beamer producing some arabic characters, I want to make all characters in math mode, bigger then the others (as much as magnification given by the command `\mathlarger` of the `relsize` package), what I can use for a specific character, but I want to make it for all my mathematical expressions, in the document. Is there a way to do the task?

I compile my documents with Xelatex, and I use the following fonts commands:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}
```

Think that you can use any arabic font command

Comment: You wrote, "I want to make all characters in math mode, bigger then the others." How much bigger? You mention you use XeLaTeX -- would you be open to use LuaLaTeX? Finally, do tell us more about your current font-related setup.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your answer. I prefer using Xelatex because a migration to LuaLatex will be difficult for me now. I'll edit my question to put the fonts command used. Thanks